# css width same as height not working

Tags: css

I have tried this and not working.

```
div {
    background:orange;
    height:20%;
    padding-left:20%;
}
```

the width become related to the window width in percent.
I want to make width equal to height in a percent value,and doing that with css only.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width") where I got that

any help please.

Comment: are you allowed to use  width property? if so there are some pretty cool answers in the link you had given that use vw units.

Comment: no I do not want to use vw units,but thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided **you are ok to change the markup**, you can add another div and achieve this with a bit of pseudo-elements added. Used the below markup.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
div.child {
  background: orange;
  height: 20%;
  margin-right: 80%;
}
.child:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding: 50% 0%;
}
div.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your `div.parent` CSS: `height: 100%:` should be `height: 100%;` with a semicolon at the end, but even then it seems the height is entirely irrelevant...